# How can I fix my SoundCloud API pagination from producing duplicates?

Tags: javascript, ajax, pagination, duplicates, soundcloud

I have been trying to grab all the favorites from a user using the Soundcloud API by getting the first 100 then following the 'next_href' property in my Ajax requests. However I end up with lots of duplicate tracks even when I can confirm the url's are different. 
Here is my code:

```
function getAllFavorites(link){
var nextLink; 
$.getJSON(link, function(data) {
   likes = data.collection;
   nextLink = data.next_href;
  $.each(likes, function(key, val) {
     if(tracks.indexOf(val) === -1){
        tracks.push(val);
        trackCount++;
     }
  });
}).done(function(){
  if (nextLink && trackPages.indexOf(nextLink) === -1){
     trackPages.push(nextLink);
     getAllFavorites(nextLink);
     console.log("Done. Next: " + nextLink);
  }else{
     finishLoading();
  }
});
```

And when looking at the produced URI's (next_href) the page_number parameter in the url is definitely increasing but sometimes will produce the same tracks. For example two consecutive URI's with 'page_number=2' for one and 'page_number=3' will produce the exact list of tracks.

Comment: could you set up a reproducible jsfiddle?